# Illegal underscore in R.java

Tags: android

After updating to Android Studio 1.3.2, I've got strange mistake

`Error:(2056, 77) error: illegal underscore`  in R.java (more details on the screenshot below)

[image: screenshot of mistake]

But name *11880432_466668553495145_5076754104009227271_n* was not found in project at all anywhere, except R.java. Also, this color was found in android support, design support libraries and android support cardview, but it has normal names there

**UPD**
There was a problem with encoding in file name in *drawable* resource directory. **Problem solved**

Comment: Resources in R must follow java variable name rules (i.e. must begin with an alphabet or underscore, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, I solved this problem doing

```
Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project
```

If it didn't solve your problem make sure that in your `Drawable` folder are not a `Drawable` with a name without `uppercase` and symbols like (@,#,$) etc.

Comment: Well, i've found a problem, thanks for advice. There was a file with corrupted encoding in name in *drawable* resources.

Comment: @AlexanderNesterenko That's why I told to you, make sure that you have a correct name on drawable folder :) Mark it as a correct if you solved your problem ^^